# issue to load the js code

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, daterangepicker

I'm working on angularjs application. I want to display dateRange picker so that user can select the dateRange(Start and end dates) from a single datepicker.
Facing issues to load the date picker. Please find the demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZHdrhQVqsceNmZoxYJ0I?p=preview)

In the console no errors are displayed, when i click on the Choose Date field datepicker is not displayed.

js code:

```
var cb = function(start, end, label) {
    console.log(start.toISOString(), end.toISOString(), label);
    $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    console.log("Callback has fired: [" + start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + " to " + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ", label = " + label + "]");
}

var optionSet1 = {
    startDate: moment().subtract(1, 'days'),
    endDate: moment().subtract(1, 'days'),
    minDate: '08/01/2014',
    maxDate: '12/31/2017',
    dateLimit: {
        days: 60
    },
    showDropdowns: true,
    showWeekNumbers: true,
    timePicker: false,
    timePickerIncrement: 1,
    timePicker12Hour: true,
    ranges: {
        'Today': [moment(), moment()],
        'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
        'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
        'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
        'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
        'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    },
    opens: 'left',
    buttonClasses: ['btn btn-default'],
    applyClass: 'btn-small btn-primary',
    cancelClass: 'btn-small',
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
    separator: ' to ',
    locale: {
        applyLabel: 'Submit',
        cancelLabel: 'Clear',
        fromLabel: 'From',
        toLabel: 'To',
        customRangeLabel: 'Custom',
        daysOfWeek: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
        monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
        firstDay: 1
    }
};

$('#reportrange span').html(moment().subtract(1, 'days').format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + moment().subtract(1, 'days').format('MMMM D, YYYY'));

$('#reportrange').daterangepicker(optionSet1, cb);

$('#reportrange').on('show.daterangepicker', function() {
  alert("show event fired");
    console.log("show event fired");
});
$('#reportrange').on('hide.daterangepicker', function() {
  alert("hide event fired");
    console.log("hide event fired");
});
$('#reportrange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    console.log("apply event fired, start/end dates are " + picker.startDate.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + " to " + picker.endDate.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
});
$('#reportrange').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    console.log("cancel event fired");
});
```

html code:

```
Choose Date : <input id="reportrange">
```

I'm having tough time in order to track the issue, do i need to import any files? I have followed this [link](http://www.daterangepicker.com/).Any suggestions would be helpful.Its not loading/triggering the below events:

```
 $('#reportrange').on('show.daterangepicker', function() {
          alert("show event fired");
            console.log("show event fired");
        });
```

Comment: I can't see track of angular here. By the way, did you wrap this code in the document ready event?
`$(document).ready(function() {$('#reportrange').on('show.daterangepicker', function() {
          alert("show event fired");
            console.log("show event fired");
        });});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will refer to the code snipped you provided as the code provided here is a bit unclear. You should just move the `<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>` tag after your input element (before `</body>` tag). The problem is that your javascript gets loaded too early and has no inputs to bind in (it doesn't know there is any input after it's executed). Moving it after the input means that the code will get executed after the input is initialized so it will be able to bind to it.

Here's your example: [fixed code snipped](http://plnkr.co/edit/k4olR0T0zh9qS9P8Vnf4?p=preview)

Comment: But in real-time or in my application, i have all imports in one jsp file, code content is in another file.I will just import the jsp file which has all the imports in code content file .I cannot include the script tag in the jsp where i have the content. Hope you got my point..

Comment: Then you need to run the script on document ready state. `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  //your script....
});`

Comment: If i have multiple datepickers in the same page and i want to reuse the same js functionality how can i achieve it. Please see the example http://plnkr.co/edit/ypgBGi10vVPe89Nq6rP7?p=preview.  Please advice.

Comment: You shouldn't use same id on more elements in html. Just rework the datepicker to initialize from `className` and not from `id`. You're now initializing from `$("#rangepicker")`, change it to `$(".rangepicker")`, also change you ids to classes and it should work